# How to store ArrayList of objects to SharedPreferences and then retrieve it?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an ExpandableListView, where a user selects different items that belong to different categories. His selections are stored in `ArrayList<Selected_Group>`. This is the code for Selected_Group object:

```
public class Selected_Group extends Group {

private int selected_group_id;
private int trip_id;
private int group_id;
private ArrayList<Selected_Item> arr_selected_items;
private int marked_counter = 0;

// Constructors...

// Getters & setters

// Other methods
}
```

Notice that the Selected_Group object also contains an ArrayList - selected items for that group.

When the activity is stopped (for a phone call, for example) I want to store the ArrayList in SharedPreferences and when it resumes - to retrieve it. Also when the user hits the Save button - remove the stored ArrayList from SharedPreferences.

Is it possible to do it? And if yes - how?

Comment: you should consider other forms of persistant storage like sqlite

Comment: All the values are being stored in sqlite db once a user hits the Save button, I want to store this ArrayList temporary in SharedPreferences in case the activity has to be recreated: after screen orientation change, or incoming phone call...

Comment: did you try onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: make your objects Parcelable and save them as putParcelableArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Why u not make it as `JsonArray`? and then convert it to String. After that u can save those String into `SharedPreferences`.below is how to make the JsonArray and convert it to string:

```
JsonArray jsArray = new JsonArray(arr_selected_items);
String strArray = jsArray.toString();
```